# TIP120 with a 3v controller

Tags: transistors

In the past I've used the [TIP120](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf) to control higher-voltage circuits (motors, valves, pumps) from an Arduino which puts out up to 5v. I'm now working on a project to control a 12v valve using a [LightBlue Bean](http://legacy.punchthrough.com/bean/) instead of an Arduino, and it only outputs 3v (60% of 5v).

If I understand correctly, the TIP120 requires 5v to the base in order to switch open the collector/emitter circuit. If I send 3v to the base nothing happens, right? This [blog post](http://chester.me/archives/2015/04/building-a-bluetooth-controlled-dry-ice-fog-machine/) suggests the TIP120 with a Bean, so I'm confused. Alternatively, is there a more appropriate transistor to use with the Bean?

Comment: It's a Darlington not a FET so it turns on quite hard between Vbe=1.2 and 1.4V. Pay suitable attention to base current (choose a suitable resistor) and you won't need more than 3V to drive it.

Comment: @Downvoter, you're supposed to comment on why you downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the TIP120 requires 5v to the base in order to switch open"

That is total nonsense. A TIP120 is a (dralington) bipolar transistor, hence it requires a base *current*. Applying 5V (without current limit) would destroy it.

When the BE junction conducts the current that 'opens' the transistor to conduct CE current, the BE junction will drop a certian voltage, as shown in this figure:
[image]

It shows that the BE voltage depends on the collector current. Let's assume you want to switch 2A, then you can expect a BE voltage of ~ 1.7 Volt. With a DC current gain of >> 2000, (figure below) a BE current of 1mA would be enough. Assuming that your uC output delivers 3V, a resistor of 1.3 / 1e-3 = 1k2 would be a good choice. Choose it a bit lower (470 ohm?) if you want to add some margin (and your uC output can handle ~ 2mA).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I barely understand what you're saying but it sounds like 3v will work! Why use a resistor at all though?

Comment: A bipolar transistor works like a diode or led. No resistor and it will pull as much current as it can, destroying itself.

Comment: @devth if you don't understand what I am saying you should seriously consider studying general electronics a bit more before you attempt to design/build your project. I am all in favour of experiments, but a little bit of insight/knowledge will enhance your chance of success considerably.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen any recommended books or courses? I've read part of "The Manga Guide to Electricity". I forget a lot though unless I apply it, so experimenting with projects like this is one of the best contexts for learning.

Comment: Maybe start with simple non-uC projects. Try electronics for dummies or something similar? Or get the real thing: the art of electronics.